# What, in the context of time, is the equivalent of "equidistant"

Tags: single-word-requests

A location, A, is said to be equidistant from two other locations, B and C, if the distance from A to B is the same as the distance from A to C.

What is the equivalent word to use in the context of time? That is, suppose that the distance from A to B is different from the distance from A to C, but it takes the same amount of time to get from A to B as it does from A to C.

Comment: I've seen *equitemporal* used in some cases. There is also *equal time*, though this doesn't meet the single-word constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both *equitemporal* (which Zairja mentioned) and *[isochronal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/isochronal)*, “... having equal duration” might work.  Google shows about 475 times as many web instances of *isochronal* as of *equitemporal* (2.4M vs 5K).  Also consider *[isochronous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/isochronous)*, in its sense “happening at the same time; isochronal”.

*Edit:* The word that occurred to me immediately upon reading the question is *[isochronic](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/isochronic)*:  “performed in equal times; said of motions and vibrations occurring at the same time and being equal in duration”.  Another interesting word is *[isochron](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/isochron)*, which (in much the same sense as in *[isochron dating](http://www.talkorigins.org/faqs/isochron-dating.html)*) means “an imaginary line or a line on a chart connecting points at which an event occurs simultaneously or which represents the same time or time difference”.  Another sense (as used in phrase *[isochronic tones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isochronic_tones)*) is “regular beats of a single tone used for brainwave entrainment”, a sense that accounts for the trade name *[Isochron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isochron)* for vasodilator drug [isosorbide dinitrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosorbide_dinitrate).

Comment: *Isochronal* is a fine, but obscure word. The term *temporal* is also a fine word, but probably not in widespread use in daily speech, and *equitemporal* would require most readers or hearers to struggle a bit with the meaning (perhaps, *at the same time*?). Maybe we need a neologism such as *equidurational*. Not common or simple, but probably clear.

Comment: @bib, I should have mentioned *isochronic*, which *might* be less obscure than *isochronal*.  See edit

Comment: OF COURSE! I had forgotten how many times I had already used *isochronic* this month!!! Probably an equiincidental number of times as I used it last month.

Comment: You'd never say 'A and B are  ___ from C.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I agree one would never say  “A and B are ___ from C”  because there is no way to say “`___`”  and have it really be “`___`”.  But one might very well write “A and B are ___ from C” when setting a problem.  (It also seems to me that your comment  “You'd never say 'A and B are ___ from C'” is not relevant to Moussa's question or my answer.)

Comment: 'A location, A, is said to be equidistant from two other locations, B and C, if the distance from A to B is the same as the distance from A to C.

What is the equivalent word to use in the context of time?' The answer, as you say, is 'There isn't one'.

Answer (score 1):

I came here with the same question, but I've realized that I had forgotten that 'equidistant' does not necessarily refer to linear space. For example, I remember reading a 1920s book that stated that two parties were "equidistant from compromise." So, like others said years ago, there is no single word for this, but that is because society has accepted linear space as the default frame for the use of 'equidistant,' so saying something is 'physically equidistant' just isn't necessary. To change that default frame, you could say that something is 'temporally equidistant.' For example, "Noon is temporally equidistant from 11 AM and 1 PM" or "The journeys from New York City to Washington and Boston are temporally equidistant." A quick Google search indicates that the phrase is fairly common in physics and philosophy papers.

Comment: You could improve this answer by quoting some of those physics and philosophy papers you referred to.