# not equidistant but 'equi-temporal'?

Tags: single-word-requests

A point is said to be equidistant from a set of objects if the distances between that point and each object in the set are equal. (Wikipedia)

Is there a word that can be used to describe two points (from one's current position) which can be reached in equal time...?  One would be 50 miles away, the other 100, but they'd both take 2 hours to reach.

(They'd be equi-temporal???)

Comment: I'd probably use a broadened sense of 'equidistant' if forced to keep it brief: "Mahwah is placed such that it's equidistant, timewise ..." and similar examples can be found on the internet.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth where's Einstein when you need him?

Comment: @michael_timofeev indeed: everywhere, (no matter where!) seems to take exactly the same amount of time to reach, in London...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider **[isochronous](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Isochrone)**:

> isochronous: equal in duration or interval

([WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=isochronous&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=))

Evidently, **equitemporal** can also be used, according to [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equitemporal&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cequitemporal%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: it appears that I have jumped the gun:  this has been asked & answered before:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80066/what-in-the-context-of-time-is-the-equivalent-of-equidistant

Comment: They are words in the same ballpark, but cannot be used to fill the slot in  'A and B are  ___ from C.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why can't you say "In terms of travel time to C, A and B are equitemporal"? The slot you describe is not set in stone, at least not in OP's question, correct?

Comment: 'Is there a word that can be used to describe two points (from one's current position) which can be reached in equal time...? One would be 50 miles away, the other 100, but they'd both take 2 hours to reach.

(They'd be equi-temporal???)' seems quite specific. They're _not_ isochronous.

Comment: If you don't like *equitemporal*, you might observe that English generally allows spatial metrics with time—“How *long* ago…”, “How *far* in the future…”, “It's *near*ly four o'clock.”, “…in the *distant* past”, “I'll be there *short*ly…”, etc. (note that "tall," as in malformed “*A *tall* time ago, in a galaxy far, far away…”, is *not* a counter-example, owing to the `short/tall` vs. `short/long` oddity in English). These license the adjective phrase "temporally equidistant," which *does* allow prepositional adjuncts (i.e., passes the substitution test proposed by @EdwinAshworth).